# Postgresql invalid input syntax for type boolean: "null"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I' learning postgresql, and I typed the following commands.

```
 CREATE TABLE t(co1 boolean, col2 text);
 INSERT INTO t VALUES(NULL, 'NULL');
 SELECT * FROM t where col2::boolean;
```

And the result came out like this:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "NULL".
```

Why is that happened since things like 'True'::boolean is correct?

Comment: And the error comes from? (CREATE, INSERT or SELECT?)

Comment: Now I see, `'NULL'` is not the null value, it's a string...

Comment: `null` is neither `true` nor `false`

Comment: What do you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I tried transforming data from text to boolean.  'True'::boolean has no error, but 'Null'::boolean return an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your col2 column is text, not boolean

```
CREATE TABLE t(co1 boolean, col2 text);
 INSERT INTO t VALUES(NULL, 'NULL');
 SELECT * FROM t where col2::text;
```